# Do I have to add all commons api?

Tags: java, api, apache-commons

I want to use commons configuration API, but when I run the project, it gives class not found exception, I googled and someone said to add commons lang api, it asked for logging and now that I put, it's asking for org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBean

What should I do?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XbNs.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use Maven to manage your project.  The problem that you saw is the dependency between projects.  Your project needs A, but A needs B, and B needs C and D, etc.  It is very tedious to manage these manually.  Maven is a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Like leeyuiwah said, you should use maven. The dependency code for Apache Commons Configuration is:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-configuration/commons-configuration -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

If for whatever reason you don't want to use maven in your project, you can download a jar with all of its dependencies at https://jar-download.com/